# Got Error while installing mysqlclient in django project on cPanel

Tags: python, mysql, django, hosting, cpanel

Requirements.txt contains:

```
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.9
django-isbn-field==0.5.3
mysql-connector-python
mysqlclient
phonenumberslite==8.12.42
Pillow==9.0.1
python-decouple==3.6
python-stdnum==1.17
pytz==2021.3
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
```

Got error:

```
Error
ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/bookbestie/virtualenv/bookbestie/3.8/bin/python3.8_bin -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nk4wll31/mysqlclient_306f3e44780f440a9c0a625d98f95d89/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-nk4wll31/mysqlclient_306f3e44780f440a9c0a625d98f95d89/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-frd2zcuu/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/bookbestie/virtualenv/bookbestie/3.8/include/site/python3.8/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/bookbestie/virtualenv/bookbestie/3.8/bin/python3.8_bin -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

[image]

I am time hosting for the first time. I browsed other posted questions but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I will suggest you to use pyMySQL instead of mysqlclient.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a hosting question, not a programming question.

Comment: @Deepak Tripathi I am installed but it while migrating it give me error

Comment: But error is saying that build is failed and build is also the part of installation.

Comment: @Deepak Tripathi No, After your suggestion. I tried pymysql after pip step i was migrating at that time i got error asking mysqlclient

Comment: Are you using django ? Then I wil share the steps to integrate PyMySQL into django.

Comment: @Deepak Tripathi Yes I am using django. Please share it will be helppful to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyMySQL version used : `pip install pymysql==1.0.2`

Django version used : `pip install django==3.2`

Then in `settings.py`

....

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

....

Then it will run fine.